# I'm using a mask to slice a numpy array, but the output is flattened. How do I retain the number of columns?

Tags: numpy, mask

Here is what I have so far:

```
arr = np.round(np.random.uniform(0,1,size = (10,10)),decimals = 0)
print(arr)
arr2 = np.cumsum(arr,axis=0)
print(arr2)
mask = np.where((arr == 1)&(arr2<=3),1,0)
print(mask)
population = np.round(np.random.uniform(0,5,size=(10,10)),decimals=0)
print(population)
maskedPop = population[mask==1]
print(maskedPop)
```

This outputs a flattened array, is there a way I can keep the 10 columns? So the output would be 3x10?

Comment: You can manually reshape it afterwards with `maskedPop.reshape(10,3)`.

Comment: When you show code with `print` you should, for politeness sake, display the results.  If you read the `numpy` docs, you'll learn that indexing with a boolean mask produces a 1d result.  SInce such a mask can select different numbers of elements in each row, it can't (in general) retain a 2d result.

Comment: Where do you get the (3,10) shape?

Comment: @hpaulj the way the mask works, there should always be at least 3 True's in each column. It would be very unlikely statistically speaking for that to not occur. Especially when I include more rows.

Comment: What difference does that make?  In my test case (5,5) the columns differ in number of True.  If there's some special structure in your `mask` you have build that into your code, and not assume that general numpy code will find it for you (nor expect us to detect it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, reduced in scale:

```
In [153]: arr = np.round(np.random.uniform(0,1,size = (5,5)),decimals = 0)
     ...: print(arr)
     ...: arr2 = np.cumsum(arr,axis=0)
     ...: print(arr2)
     ...: mask = np.where((arr == 1)&(arr2<=3),1,0)
     ...: print(mask)
     ...: population = np.round(np.random.uniform(0,5,size=(5,5)),decimals=0)
     ...: print(population)
     ...: print(mask==1)
     ...: maskedPop = population[mask==1]
     ...: print(maskedPop)
```

The print results - I added the `mask==1` line, since that's what's doing the indexing:

```
[[0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 2. 1. 2.]
 [2. 1. 2. 2. 3.]
 [3. 2. 2. 2. 4.]
 [3. 2. 2. 2. 4.]]
[[0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
[[0. 5. 2. 2. 2.]
 [1. 4. 2. 4. 0.]
 [2. 3. 3. 2. 2.]
 [4. 4. 3. 1. 3.]
 [4. 2. 2. 1. 5.]]
[[False  True  True False  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True]
 [ True False False  True  True]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [False False False False False]]
[5. 2. 2. 1. 2. 4. 0. 2. 2. 2. 4. 4.]
```

Count the number of `True` per row or column.  Tell us how this could retain some sort of 2d result!

===

I see you already display `mask`, so `mask==` is the same as

```
In [158]: mask.astype(bool)
Out[158]: 
array([[False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

There is a `MaskedArray` class that lets you work with an array with certain values 'masked-out':

```
In [161]: np.ma.masked_array(population, mask!=1)
Out[161]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, 5.0, 2.0, --, 2.0],
        [1.0, --, 2.0, 4.0, 0.0],
        [2.0, --, --, 2.0, 2.0],
        [4.0, 4.0, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --]],
  mask=[[ True, False, False,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True, False, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

===

Another way to retain masked values in an array is to somehow 'zero-out' values:

```
In [162]: mpop = population.copy()
In [163]: mpop[mask!=1] = np.nan
In [164]: mpop
Out[164]: 
array([[nan,  5.,  2., nan,  2.],
       [ 1., nan,  2.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 2., nan, nan,  2.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  4., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

Comment: zeroing out is the only way it seems, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the maks produces the same amount of non-zero rows per column. So you could probably mask (using the boolean array directly) and `reshape`:

```
population[(arr == 1)&(arr2<=3)].reshape(3,-1)

array([[3., 2., 5., 0., 4., 2., 0., 4., 5., 1.],
       [4., 3., 5., 3., 4., 1., 1., 4., 5., 4.],
       [3., 3., 4., 3., 4., 2., 4., 4., 1., 5.]])
```

Note that the output is flattened, since numpy doesn't know that the result is expected to be a 2d homogeneous array. If `mask.sum(0)` resulted in different values per column, you wouldn't be able to reconstruct as an ndarray, so numpy just doesn't do that guess for you.

Comment: Its not keeping the results in the correct column though... how do I keep the masked results in the same column from the original population array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you add the expected output? @lara_toff